# How to add more system event sound effects in Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, audio, cinnamon

How can I add more sounds to different system events on Linux for different actions or events? For example by default on some Linux desktops, say Linux Mint for example, you get sound effects when you take a screenshot, or open and close windows.

But what about having sound notifications trigger for other certain dialogs or important things that needs attention? I'd like to know how system sounds are triggered for certain event, and how can also be made so that it shows up in the Sound Effects tab of Sound panel for System Preferences so it can be changed at any time?

[image: Sound panel of System Preferences]

Comment: I don't use Mint/Cinnamon so no idea how to make new-sounds show up in that panel. Anyway, here is the link to the spec: [Sound Naming Specification](http://0pointer.de/public/sound-naming-spec.html)

Comment: That's on Cinnamon, right? Sound effects depend on the desktop environment.

Comment: @don_crissti that's pretty useful link there.

Comment: @Gilles It doesn't entirely depend on the desktop environment, but the theme it's using.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Cinnamon mint 18.1.

It has been very frustrating discovering how to add new sounds to the sound scheme.

Then I found, by accident, the active ogg files are stored in `/usr/share/mint artwork`. Huh? Yes, artwork.

I extracted my sounds to `/usr/share/sounds` then -Right clicked on 'files' in the navigation tree of the home icon and opened with supervisor privileges, Navigated to the correct place, `mint artwork`, and pasted the sound file copies there.

Now my mint system sounds are Nintendo sounds.

Answer (score 1):

Just letting anyone that has 18.3 Sylvia know it's in:

```
/usr/share/mint-artwork-cinnamon/sounds
```