# Linux Mint Cinnamon - Play A Sound On Lock?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

On Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.3, I'd like to set a sound to be played when the system "Locks" (i.e. by closing the lid, screensaver, etc).  However, there appears to be no such option under Preferences->Sound->Sounds (it has options for Starting & Leaving Cinnamon, but none for locking).  If anyone could point me to how can I can do this, I'd be much appreciative - I've spent a fair bit of time Googling, so far to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If by "desktop manager" you mean "windows manager," it's mentioned as Cinnamon. If by "desktop manager" you mean "file manager," it's Nemo (the default for Linux Mint). If it's something else, I'm not sure what you're asking for, nor how it's relevant to the question?

Comment: my mistake ... too early in the morning ... cinnamon is the desktop manager

Comment: i do not have cinnamon installed ... look at the link in the first comment ... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207636/how-to-add-more-system-event-sound-effects-in-cinnamon ... http://0pointer.de/public/sound-naming-spec.html

Comment: Thanks for the link - yeah, I actually found that previously. The existing sounds don't follow that naming convention though, & I tried "desktop-screen-lock" anyway. Didn't pick it up.

Comment: found this ... https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=277710 ... it has crossed my mind that perhaps you need to create a `desktop-screen-lock.ogg` file

Comment: My previous comment: 'I tried "desktop-screen-lock" anyway. Didn't pick it up.' ;)  (I tried putting it in all 3 places - /usr/share/sounds/LinuxMint/stereo /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo, & /usr/share/mint-artwork/sounds - and restarting the PC fully.  No go.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: I ended up giving up & moving to Kubuntu (KDE Plasma), in which it took about 10 seconds to configure this in the UI.

As I've since done even more Googling, & left this question up for a month with no luck, I'm going to assume that the answer is **"You can't do it in Cinnamon, so if you want this functionality, try another Desktop Environment."**